# allow incoming calls to interrupt mobile broadband connection

Tags: network-manager

I've moved into a new apartment where I can't get decent internet.  However, I can connect via my mobile edge network.  Just one problem: when someone tries to call my cell phone when I am connected, they cannot get through, and I never know about the call.

If I use the phone's own browser/email and it connects to edge, an incoming call will interrupt the connection.  This is what I want.  Is there a way to enable this in Ubuntu?

(I used the 'mobile broadband' section of the network manager to set-up the connection.)

Comment: Unless your phone accepts calls when used as a modem under Windows, then this may be a limitation of your phone rather than how Ubuntu uses it.  Perhaps provide some details about the phone itself?

Comment: Sorry for the very long delay in responding.  It may well be a problem with the phone.  Sometimes it allows interrupts, sometimes not, and now that I think of it, this is the behaviour even under windows.  (Nokia E63).  It's just an issue I'll have to live with, I think.  Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP has resolved the issue themselves,

> Sorry for the very long delay in responding. It may well be a problem
>   with the phone. Sometimes it allows interrupts, sometimes not, and now
>   that I think of it, this is the behaviour even under windows. (Nokia
>   E63). It's just an issue I'll have to live with, I think.